# lambda container image serverless

Tags: aws-lambda, dockerfile, serverless

I have a working lambda deployment using serverless.  I am trying to put the lambda functions inside a docker image.  Originally I had a handler.js that contains 2 module.exports and in my original serverless.yml I specified:

```
functions:
  func1:
    handler: handler.func1
    events:
      ...
  func2:
    handler: handler.func2
    events:
      ...
```

The new serverless.yml is as follows:

```
functions:
  func1:
    image: <account>.dkr.ecr.<region>.amazonaws.com/<repository>@<digest>
    events:
      ...
  func2:
    image: <account>.dkr.ecr.<region>.amazonaws.com/<repository>@<digest>
    events:
      ...
```

My question is, what do I put into the CMD in the Dockerfile so I can access both func1 and func2?

Currently I have:

```
FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/nodejs:14
ARG FUNCTION_DIR="/var/task"

# Create function directory
RUN mkdir -p ${FUNCTION_DIR}

# Copy handler function and package.json
COPY handler.js ${FUNCTION_DIR}
COPY package.json ${FUNCTION_DIR}

# Install NPM dependencies for function
RUN npm install

# Set the CMD to your handler
CMD [ "handler" ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using the AWS base image for Node.js, you have to define your `handler` like you did in `serverless.yml`. Like this:

```
CMD [ "handler.func1" ]
```

There's a very similar example to your code in the [AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/images-create.html#images-create-1) which explains how you should set the `CMD` arguments.

The CMD arguments are provided to the `ENTRYPOINT`. From the [AWS Docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/images-create.html#images-parms):

> CMD – Specifies parameters that you want to pass in with ENTRYPOINT.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  If I specify CMD ["handler.func1"] how do I access func2?

Comment: You need a second container for your second function then ;) You only specify the `handler` property when you zip your function (instead of using an image).